# Hi smart people, i have problem with (many to many) assocation with sequelize orm

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have problem with (many to many) assocation with sequelize orm

In my case i have 3 tables

products,
categories,
products_categories

and here are assocation in nodeJS

```
Product.belongsToMany(Categories, {
  through: {
    model: ProductsCategories,
    as: 'products_categories',
  },
  foreignKey: "category_id"
})

Categories.belongsToMany(Product, {
  through: {
    model: ProductsCategories,
    as: 'products_categories',
  },
  foreignKey: "product_id"
})
```

when i'm trying to fetch products with categories
sequelize not gives me back categories of the product

here are example

```
 const products = await Product.findAll({
      include:{
        model:Categories,
        nested:true,
        through:{
            model: ProductsCategories,
            as: 'products_categories',
        }
      }
    });
```

---

please help me understand where are my mistak ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your model definitions as:

```
Product.belongsToMany(Categories, {
  through: ProductsCategories,
  as: 'products_categories',
  foreignKey: "category_id"
})

Categories.belongsToMany(Product, {
  through: ProductsCategories,
  as: 'products_categories',
  foreignKey: "product_id"
})
```

and findAll:

```
 const products = await Product.findAll({
      include:{
        model:Categories,
        as: 'products_categories'
      }
    });
```

Comment: i allready fixed problem, problem in incorrect foreignKeys  anyway thanks for replay =))